# How to add a timeout in get request in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, get, timeout

I have a below code which queries a URL:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url="<url>", timeout=(3, 6))
if "File Not Found in Database" in r.text:
    print("Incorrect URL")
else:
    print("Correct URL")
```

It's making a GET call for a URL. If URL is correct, file is downloaded otherwise it says error `File Not Found in Database`. When URL is correct, I don't need to download the file but I just want to check if URL is correct or not.

So I want to add a timeout because if URL is incorrect, it will throw error `File Not Found in Database` but if it's correct, I just want to timeout and print correct URL. But it looks like this timeout is not working or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the timeout with this exception:

```
import requests

url = "<url>"
try:
    r = requests.get(url=url, timeout=(3, 6))
    if "File Not Found in Database" in r.text:
        print("Incorrect URL")
    else:
        print("Correct URL")
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print("The request timed out.")
```

Comment: This is not working. Actually when the url is correct, the code is stuck at `r = requests.get(url=url, timeout=(3, 6))` because I think its downloading the file which I do not want and thus want a timeout

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HEAD` HTTP method to check if a file exists without downloading it. The `HEAD` method is similar to `GET`, but it only returns the header information and not the actual content.

```py
import requests

url = "<URL>"

response = requests.head(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("File exists.")
elif response.status_code == 404:
    print("File not found.")
else:
    print(f"An unexpected status code was returned: {response.status_code}")
```

This doesn't exactly pertain to "adding a timeout to a request" but it better achieves your goal.

IMO that's what matters.

Comment: Problem is that the API returns 200 in both the cases so using head() will not make sense but thanks for your comment

Comment: If it's not returning an error code, maybe you could try checking what `Content-Type` it returns?